# deleting image from the storage folder in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete the image from the storage folder at the time of deleting from the database also.

The image file is getting deleted from database but unable to delete from server storage folder.

The image is getting stored in http://url.com/foldername/files/newsletter

The below is the code i used..

```
<?php

$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);

include 'db/connection.php';



$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from tablename where id=$id");
$results=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);

if($results["file"]!="") {  
    $image=$results["file"];
    unlink("../files/newsletter/".$image);
    }



$sql = "delete from tablename where id=$id";

$result = @mysql_query($sql);


if ($result){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
}

?>
```

Plz help in resolving..Thank you

Comment: Do you have any errors? are you positive about the path of the file?

Comment: Better to use absolute directory path.. relative may occur issue with file location!!

Comment: Yeah try to change `unlink("../files/newsletter/".$image);` to `unlink("/var/www/foldername/files/newsletter/".$image);` and see what happens. Totes to Shaunak Shukla, for pointing out the use of Absolute

Comment: Try to make sure that the file actually exists (file_exists() function) and that you have the permission to delete it.

Also, unlink returns false in case of error.
So, do something like that:

    `if (!unlink("../files/newsletter/".$image)){
       throw new Exception("Could not delete file");
    }`

Comment: give the path from your `root directory` in `unlink` like `home/sk/public_html/files/ ...` because may be you are accessing the wrong path in unlink

Answer (score 0):

try to add document root with your code to something like code below.

```
$imageWithPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/newsletter/".$image;
@unlink($imageWithPath);
```

Comment: what's the use of @ in unlink?

Comment: @RamSharma if `files`  folder is not in root then ? like ` [root]/sk/files/...`?

Comment: if image doesn't exist than it will not through the error/warning/notice.

Comment: I have seen that as well in @f open pls elaborate this. Thanks

Comment: @JohnRobertson i am asking this to Rama Sharma

Comment: @SKRocks you can't delete image/files on other/different server in that case using php. if you don't have access to that directory.

Comment: can't we have access on online server to delete the stored files from that folder

Comment: if you want to delete files with PHP script than you should have both files(image and php) on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print out what your $results["file"] value is and check.

You are using mysql_fetch_array it should be inside while loop

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from tablename where id=$id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
    $image = $row["file"];
    //make sure below path is correct.
    $image_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/foldername/files/newsletter/'.$image;
    echo $image_path;//you can compare if the path is correct or not
    //Also check if file exists here
    if(file_exists(image_path)){
       unlink($image_path);
    }
    else{
      echo 'file doesnot exist';
    }
}
```

Also you will need to have permissions to be able to delete the file. Make sure the apache or user that runs your script file have correct permission or ownership of the file.

Comment: i tried the above code..it's not deleting from folder..what is DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: when running the script file do you get file doesnot exist printed?

Comment: no..i'm not getting any message - file doesnot exist

Comment: you are not getting anything printed out?

Comment: i'm not getting any printed message

Comment: Are you sure you are not running this script on already deleted id?